# Installing ethernet jacks in garage just below ceiling level

Tags: cabling, building-regulations, ethernet

I live in UK in a 2-storey semi-detached house built in 1946. We are in the process of building an extension to the side of it - with garage on the ground floor and a bedroom above the garage.  The shell is already built and the internal fitting is still in progress.

I am about to install an IP video security system with 7 cameras around the house. All cameras are PoE, that is only require ethernet cable for connection. The easiest thing for me is to route a bunch of network cables into the garage, install two 4-jack faceplates and route all cables from the cameras into the garage.

The house is already fully wired with CAT6 and a cupboard under the stairs contains the patch panel and the switch.  The garage is adjacent to the cupboard, and there is already a hole through the wall, through which electrical cables are routed.  The hole is big enough for me to route additional 8 CAT6 cables - so it's very easy to get ethernet connections into the garage. (CAT6 cable I am using is fully shielded - each pair is foil wrapped and the whole cable is in a metal mesh under the top insulation - therefore I am not too worried about the interference.

Now, convenience-wise, it's best for me to install these ethernet jacks in the garage closer to ceiling level (say, a foot or so below the ceiling).  This way there will be the least amount of cabling in the garage.

The question I have is whether I would have problems with building regulations - with connection point so high up.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know for your locale, but I would doubt any trouble - we often put them in the middle of the ceiling (best place to mount an access point.) In general they are much less regulated than electrical outlets.